# Very low producer message rates caused by message delivery constraints

Tags: apache-kafka

## Producer Message Delivery Constraints

I am working on a system which has the following Kafka Producer message delivery constraints:

- Messages must be delivered once and only once (no repeats)
- Messages must be delivered in order, reordering of messages is not permitted

## Producer ACK options

When publishing a message to a Kafka system from a producer, there are a number of options to specify how and when it should be considered to be "committed".

1. **"ACKS = none":** As far as I am aware, this is a "fire and forget" mode. A producer dispatches the data across the network and does not care whether the data arrives or not. It also does not care if the data arrives to the lead broker, is written to the lead brokers log, and then the lead broker dies, meaning the message is lost because none of the followers have the data. A new leader is then elected, and the new leader is missing the data. In summary, there is no logic in place to ensure a message is delivered, you are reliant on the network being stable and the brokers not falling over.
2. **"ACKS = 1":** In this mode, the producer does not consider the message to be committed until it has received an ACK from the lead broker. This guarantees message delivery, but doesn't protect against the above described failure whereby the leader dies before it has emitted a copy of the data to the followers. You would generally expect this to be quite a safe option, because if the leader does die, this is probably such a serious failure that the whole system needs to be halted. (At least in some contexts - eg: you now have bigger problems to deal with.) It is also a fairly unlikely failure mode.
3. **"ACKS = all":** Finally, this mode does not emit an ack until all followers have emitted an ack to the leader. The leader then emits an ack to the producer, which indicates that the leader and all followers (replicas) have written the message to their logs.

## The problem: Very low message throughput rates

The producers currently have message rates limited to about 10 messages per second. This is because the code calls `producer.flush()` after every message is sent.

If I understand correctly, what `producer.flush()` does is dispatch all messages in the producers pending message queue, and wait for the specified number of acks to come back.

- In this case, the specified number of acks is 1. (Option 2, above.)

The ping times are good. Between 0.1 ms and 1 ms depending on which broker is pinged. The network connections are all datacenter quality multi-gigabit connections. Messages are typically small, less than 1 kB in size.

If `producer.flush()` is removed, message rates exceed 100,000 / second.

The question is, is the `producer.flush()` necessary to ensure messages are delivered according to the requirements? If `producer.flush()` is **not** called after every message is produced, then I do not understand how message ordering and exactly once delivery can be guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

based on your requirements you need to ensure the producer configuration for `enable.idempotence` is set to true, which is the default but this requires some other configurations to be aligned (acks all, max inflight...) as described in the [official documentation here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs_enable.idempotence). If you follow those guidelines described in the documentation and follow the [single writer principle](https://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.com/2011/09/single-writer-principle.html), i.e. - make sure to have a single thread and producer sending the data and feed that producer in order you will have such guarantees you described.

You don't need / should not call flush after each message or you will lose the automatic optimization done on the network buffers by the producer for you, this will not hurt the aforementioned requested guarantees.
If you want a full end to end guarantee from Producer to Consumer you will need to configure your consumer to have `isolation.level` set to `read_committed`.

With those configurations Kafka provides exactly once guarantee delivery.

Comment: Idempotence is enabled, and only a single thread is being used.

Without the call to flush, what prevents the running process from processing more incoming data without having guaranteed that the produced messages have been saved?

In other words, how do I structure the consumer commit logic to cope with the fact that just because I have produced some messages, doesn't guarantee they have been committed on the producer side?

Comment: Ah I see you want an end to end guarantee from producer all the way to consuming(this was not clear in your question) anyways this is also possible, search for exactly once and you will find it.. I am a bit in a rush today but will make sure to update the answer in the weekend with the details.

Comment: Fair point. I've just been reading about "exactly once processing" and the concept of transactions. You're right, I should have perhaps provided more detail but the question was already quite long. While I understand how transactions would provide exactly once message processing in a **stateless** application, I do not understand how one is supposed to integrate state into such an application. In particular, when the amount of state is very large.

Comment: There is a further problem - that of shared state. It is fairly obvious that an application cannot have shared state across multiple processes, unless those processes have a way to communicate. (Which they don't - otherwise using Kafka doesn't make a lot of sense. Why introduce yet another communication layer?) Some types of data processing application can have independent "bits of state" which can be split across multiple processes, and that state does not interact, so those processes can be scaled horrizontally.

Comment: However - then how does one handle a consumer reballance? If an application is split across multiple processes, and the state in those processes is all independent, and each process reads data from a different Kafka partition, then what happens if the consumer group grows or shrinks? We will get a reballance and the keys being consumed by each process can in principle become randomized. How do we deal with that? The existing process state is no longer independent of the new process state.

Comment: Hi I understand you have many doubts, I edited my answer to provide full setup for end to end from producer to consumer exactly once guarantees. I recommend you ask  new threads/questions as it require more extensive explanations. Short: You don't have to worry about rebalances and failover if you set up correctly. Kakfa takes care of that. Look for changelog topic recovery and about local state you can look for kafka streams KTables which uses rocksdb with proper replicas and also capable to auto recovering from changelog topics. Keep it up, you're clearly learning a lot. Way to go.

Comment: You're right. I should ask a seperate question at this point.